# Alternative to File explorer that supports undo operation

Tags: file-management

In Windows 11, I am looking for an alternative file explorer that supports undo operation. Initially, I tried One-Commander which is amazing but unfortunately, it doesn't support undo operation: https://groups.google.com/g/onecommander/c/MPulb-a-l1g

What I mean by undo operation is to ability to return to the previous state of files as the regular file explorer of Windows has. For instance, when you accidentally delete a file, you simply press ctrl+z to return it back.

Comment: WDYM? Windows Explorer does support undoing deletion with Ctrl + Z. Unless you e.g. delete the files from trash.

Comment: what I mean was restoring file from trash or undoing rename of file